# How can I repeat a function?

Tags: python, function, math

I want to define a function with n and s as arguments. The function has to print s a total
of n times. Then I want to print Pencil! n times (n is a random integer
between 1 and 1000) using the function defined.

This is my code:

```
def funz(s,n):
    x=((((s*n)+'\n')*n)[:-1])
    return x

def repeat(s,n)
    for k in range(1,1000):
    return ('Pencil!')
```

Can you help me correct what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `random.randint()` to select a random number from 1 to 100, then pass this as the `n` argument to `funz()`

```
import random

def funz(s,n):
    x = (s+"\n")*(n-1) + s
    return x

print(funz("Hello world!", random.randint(1, 100)))
```

Comment: How? Can you put this in my code?

Comment: Updated the answer